# My simple calculator don't do operations fine with double number

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a basic calculator and seems that works fine, unless when I try to sum/divide... a double number like for example 5.5

Then, if I try do this: 5.5 + 1 the result that I get is 56 and not 6.5. Seems that my logic don't take the point when do the operations.

Some help will be apreciate!

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputText.getText().toString().length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(inputText.getText().toString().charAt(i))) {
                    val += inputText.getText().toString().substring(i, i + 1);
                    if (i == inputText.getText().toString().length() - 1) {
                        vals.add(Double.parseDouble(val));
                    }
                } else if (inputText.getText().toString().substring(i, i + 1).equals("+")) {
                    vals.add(Double.parseDouble(val));
                    signs.add("+");
                    val = "";
                } else if (inputText.getText().toString().substring(i, i + 1).equals("-")) {
                    vals.add(Double.parseDouble(val));
                    signs.add("-");
                    val = "";
                } else if (inputText.getText().toString().substring(i, i + 1).equals("*")) {
                    vals.add(Double.parseDouble(val));
                    signs.add("*");
                    val = "";
                } else if (inputText.getText().toString().substring(i, i + 1).equals("/")) {
                    vals.add(Double.parseDouble(val));
                    signs.add("/");
                    val = "";
                }
            }

 double result = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < vals.size(); i++){
            if (i == 0){
                result = vals.get(i);
            }
            else {
                String sign = signs.get(i-1);
                switch (sign){
                    case "+":
                        result = vals.get(i) + result;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = result - vals.get(i);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result = result / vals.get(i);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = result * vals.get(i);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

 1. I think that the problem is in this part of the code:

                //I can check the value of vals is 5.5 here when do the first loop in for loop
                ArrayList<Double> vals = new ArrayList<>();

    //but here the value of val is 55 and not 5.5
    val +=  inputText.getText().toString().substring(i, i + 1); //Then, I'm
        adding in the array the 55 instead the 5.5 if (i ==
        inputText.getText().toString().length() - 1) {
                                vals.add(Double.parseDouble(val));
                            }
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal snippet of code that has the problem you are experiencing. Try checking the values at various points until you can identify what part of the code is wrong.

Comment: is it allow multiple operations like 1+2-3 ? or just 1 operation at a time

Comment: Hi. The problem is in this line:                     val += inputText.getText().toString().substring(i, i + 1);

Comment: Multiple operations

Comment: I've just edit my question adding the code where I think that is the error

Comment: the problem you are reading a single character at a time so, `5.6` is considering 56 or may be 5+6 (in other case). you have to input the `String` then split that string with `+ - % / * ` and the arrayitems you got, operate on those

Comment: Hi samir. Can you provide me a bit of code of how can I do this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this condition:

```
if (Character.isDigit(inputText.getText().toString().charAt(i))) {
    val += inputText.getText().toString().substring(i, i + 1);
    if (i == inputText.getText().toString().length() - 1) {
        vals.add(Double.parseDouble(val));
    }
```

You collect all digits from your `String` in `val`, stopping at `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. **You ignore all other characters**, they don't fall into any of the `else`s and as such just result in no operation and the loop advances. What happens with an input of `5.5+1`?

- `5` gets added to `val`
- `.` gets ignored
- `5` gets added to `val`: now it's `55`
- `+`: `"55"` is parsed to `vals[0] = 55`, `"+"` is put into `signs[0]`
- `1` gets added to `val`, the code detects it's the end of the string, so it parses `"1"` as `vals[1] = 1`.

The rest of the code happily computes `55 + 1` and you'll never find out.

Effectivity of the code aside, you should

1. change the condition to

   ```
   if (Character.isDigit(inputText.getText().toString().charAt(i))
       || inputText.getText().toString().charAt(i) == '.') {
   ```
2. add a final `else` that reports any fall-through characters as warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ScriptEngine`

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
Object result = engine.eval(editText1.getText().toString());
editText1.setText(result.toString());
```